# ¿Se puede poner archivos como recursos dentro de un proyecto de Visual Studio, tal como las imágenes?

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, visual-studio, archivo

Quería consultar si es posible poner dentro de un proyecto de Visual Studio archivos a los que se pueda acceder al correr el programa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que estos archivos queden dentro del copilado y que se puedan acceder como una colección de archivos al momento de la ejecución.
Mí idea principal es que al actualizarse el programa estos archivos se actualicen y lo primero que haga la aplicación sea chequear con la base si la versión de los archivos está actualizada y en caso contrario solicitar al usuario la password de root y mandar a ejecutar las actualizaciones sobre la base.

Desde ya les agradezco

Comment: Sí, sí se puede.

Comment: ¿Sabés como accedo? Estuve buscando y no encontré

Comment: por la imagen que pone, pareciera que quiere conectarse a una base de datos, hay varios tutoriales en la web sobre el tema, debes buscar crud (create, read, update y delete) con el motor de base de datos que quieras por ejemplo mysql y C#
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ly7aJFTldgw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seleccionas el archivo y presionas F4 para abrir el cuadro de propiedades (si lo tuvieras cerrado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pones

- Acción de compilador: Recurso Incrustado
- Copiar en directorio de salida: Copiar Siempre

**¿Como leer un recurso incrustado?**

```
namespace ConsoleApp29
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            System.IO.Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApp29.test.1.png");
        }
    }
```

Hacer notar que:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**¿Como listar los recursos incrustado?**

```
namespace ConsoleApp29
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("ConsoleApp29");
            var resources = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Assembly.Load(assemblyName).GetManifestResourceNames());
            Console.WriteLine(resources);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente. Lo pruebo y te califico. Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: La lectura directa del archivo me funcionó excelente.
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                    System.IO.Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("PA100TE.scripts.20230105.sql");

                    string st = StreamToString(stream);

Comment: Ahora, el listado de los archivos me tira una excepcion

 var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("PA100TE");
                    var resources = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Assembly.Load(assemblyName).GetManifestResourceNames());
                    Console.WriteLine(resources);

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'PA100TE' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.'

Comment: Ya está. Va el nombre de la solución, yo ponía el del espacio. Que en tu ejemplo es el mismo. 

Muchas GRacias!!!!

Comment: @MRossi Claro!!! Disculpa por la confusión!!